# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. on new App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, security

I created a new app by following this tutorial

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bspann/archive/2013/01/19/asp-net-mvc-based-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-on-premises.aspx

I was able to press F5 and it showed me the Do you Trust it screen, and I installed.

Code is like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Uri hostWeb = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
            using (
                var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb,
                    Request.LogonUserIdentity))
            {
                var web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web, w=>w.Lists.Include(l=>l.Title).Where(l=>!l.Hidden));
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                return View(web.Lists);
            }
        }
```

I checked the HOST WEB and my username is on the Owners group.
I debuggeed and Request.LogonUnserIdentity is showing my username, so that means the app is being executed under my identity which is ok

Whats happening then?

I noticed that when do F5, the url in ths browser is with localhost 
I had to replace it because this site wont let me put localhost, looool!

https://mysuperxxxxx.com:44301/Home?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fbe%2Dappsdev003%2Ebe%2Eema%2Emycompanynameinternal%2Ecom&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4481%2E1005

I found this on my ULS Logs

```
SPApplicationAuthenticationModule: Error authenticating request, Error details: Header: 3000006;reason="Token contains invalid signature.";category="invalid_client", Body: {"error_description":"Invalid JWT token. Could not resolve issuer token."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to run some steps needed for an app to work in a dev environment.
They are well explained here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179901.aspx